# Angular 4 template *ngIf not updating after response received

Tags: javascript, angular

It seems like, for some reason, my template is not updating to show an object that is nevertheless being properly received

Simple template to show the *date* property, *cast-detail.component.html*

```
<div *ngIf="cast">
  {{ cast.date }}
</div>
```

*cast-detail.component.ts*

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';

import { Cast } from './cast';
import { CastsService } from './casts.service';

import { PicService } from './pic.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cast-detail',
  templateUrl: './cast-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cast-detail.component.css']
})
export class CastDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  cast: Cast;
  pics: string[];

  constructor(
    private castsService: CastsService,
    private picService: PicService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.paramMap
      .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => this.castsService.getCast(params.get('date')))
      .subscribe(cast => {this.cast = cast; console.log(this.cast)});


    this.route.paramMap
      .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => this.picService.getPics(params.get('date')))
      .subscribe(pics => this.pics = pics);
  }

}
```

`console.log(this.cast)` shows that the object is received properly at some point, but the template is never updated, it just renders nothing. What I find even more confusing is that the PicService, which just provides an array of strings, works perfectly fine. I also have a component that displays a list of casts, relying on CastService, that also functions perfectly fine. Both of those work without the *ngIf tag... but the `{{ cast.date }}` property throws the error `TypeError: _co.cast is undefined` without an *ngIf, and just never updates if *ngIf is there.

My two services, which are fairly simple:

*casts.service.ts*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class CastsService {
  api: string = 'http://localhost:3000/api/casts';

  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

  getCast(date: string) {
    const url = `${this.api}/${date}`;
    return this.http.get(url)
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

  getAllCasts() {
    return this.http.get(this.api)
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

*pic.service.ts*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class PicService {
  api: string = "http://localhost:3000/api/pic";

  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

  getPics(date: string) {
    const url = `${this.api}/${date}`;
    return this.http.get(url)
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: That does sound a bit strange, I see nothing strange going on, but I might be blind :D Could you reproduce the issue in a demo? Also, just as a comment, instead of *ngIf, you could use the safe navigation operator, or simply initialize `cast`.

Comment: Sounds like you're having issues with type `Cast`. If a property of type `Cast` is setting you'll have an issue. In the `Cast` definition, I would set `date?: <datatype>;`. The `?` is key if at anytime or in the template try safe navigation `{{ cast?.date }}` https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#expression-operators.

Comment: It looks like using the safe navigation operator has the same result as *ngIf, no update. Initializing the cast's date property manually like `.subscribe(cast => {this.cast = cast; this.cast.date = '20170729'});` allows me to render `{{ cast.date }}`. I'll put together a demo to try and reproduce.

Comment: Try debugging the view with a `cast | json` to see what it receives.

Comment: `{{ cast | json }}` revealed that the JSON object I was receiving was actually an array of one Cast, rather than a Cast object!! Rookie mistake :) thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed the same issue in my code too, and I solved it by forcing the change detection cycle. The this.cdr.detectChanges() should do the magic.

Using ChangeDetectorRef:

```
import {
Component,
OnInit,
ChangeDetectorRef
} from '@angular/core';

constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef, ....) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.paramMap
        .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => this.castsService.getCast(params.get('date')))
        .subscribe(cast => {
            this.cast = cast;
            console.log(this.cast);
            this.cdr.detectChanges();
    });
}
```

Alternate solution can be, converting 'cast' to 'Observable' type and using 'async' pipe in HTML.

```
<div *ngIf="!!(cast$ | async)">
  {{ (cast$ | async).date }}
```

```
import {
Component,
OnInit,
ChangeDetectorRef
} from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

cast$: Observable<Cast>;

constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef, ....) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.cast$ = this.route.paramMap
    .switchMap((params: ParamMap) => this.castsService.getCast(params.get('date')))
    .map(cast => {
        console.log(cast);
        return cast;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, but my problem was simpler than this! I noted the issue in a comment on the original post